# Checking what values ​the user checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I create a simple vehicle configurator for the purposes of learning React. The user selects the engine model, gearbox type etc. I am already finishing the project and I learned a lot thanks to it, but I have one last problem. I would like to add simple logic to my application.

I mean this type of logic, so I would write it in pure JavaScript.

```
if (carModel === "wk" && carEngine === !"2.0 166bhp") {
        alert("You can't pick this engine!")
    }
```

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import styles from './style.module.scss';

const ModelsTypes = [
    {
        name: "pro rs3",
        price: 100000,
    },
    {
        name: "uber rs2",
        price: 50000,
    },
    {
        name: "standard",
        price: 10000,
    },
    {
        name: "wk",
        price: 5000,
    },
]

const EngineTypes = [
    {
        name: "5.2l 532bhp",
        price: 10000,
    },
    {
        name: "4.2l 443bhp",
        price: 9000,
    },
    {
        name: "3.6 374bhp",
        price: 5000,
    },
    {
        name: "2.0 166bhp",
        price: 1000,
    },
]

const Gearbox = [
    {
        gearbox: "Manual",
        price: 5000,
    },
    {
        gearbox: "Automatic",
        price: 10000,
    },
]


export const CarCustomization = () => {

    const [carModel, setCarModel] = useState("");
    const [carEngine, setCarEngine] = useState("");
    const [carGearbox, setCarGearbox] = useState("");
    const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);

    const [switchToggled, setSwitchToggled] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setTotalPrice((carModel.price + carEngine.price + carGearbox.price) || 0);
    }, [carModel, carEngine, carGearbox])

    const addCarModel = (e) => {
        setCarModel(carModel => ModelsTypes.find(x => x.name === e.target.value));
    }

    const addCarEngine = (e) => {
        setCarEngine(carEngine => EngineTypes.find(x => x.name === e.target.value));
    }

    const addCarGearbox = (e) => {
        setCarGearbox(carGearbox => Gearbox.find(x => x.gearbox === e.target.value));
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            <div>
                <h1>CKONFIG 5.1</h1>
                <section>
                    <p className={styles.sectionName}>Model</p>
                    <div className={styles.itemWrapper}>
                        {ModelsTypes.map(model =>
                            <label className={styles.button}>
                                <input onClick={addCarModel} type="radio" name="Model" value={model.name}/>
                                <span>{model.name}</span>
                            </label>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <p className={styles.sectionName}>Engine</p>
                    <div className={styles.itemWrapper}>
                        {EngineTypes.map(engine =>
                            <label className={styles.button}>
                                <input onClick={addCarEngine} type="radio" name="Engine" value={engine.name}/>
                                <span>{engine.name}</span>
                            </label>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <p className={styles.sectionName}>Gearbox</p>
                    <div className={styles.itemWrapper}>
                        {Gearbox.map(gearbox =>
                            <label className={styles.button}>
                                <input onClick={addCarGearbox} type="radio" name="Gearbox"
                                       value={gearbox.gearbox}/>
                                <span>{gearbox.gearbox}</span>
                            </label>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.summary}>
                <div className={styles.summaryinfo}>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Model</li>
                        <li>Engine</li>
                        <li>Gearbox</li>
                        <li>Price</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li>{carModel.name}</li>
                        <li>{carEngine.name}</li>
                        <li>{carGearbox.gearbox}</li>
                        <li>${totalPrice}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I was thinking about conditional rendering in the summary section here, but when I tried to add it, the application stopped returning the name of the selected engine.

Comment: `if (carModel === "wk" && carEngine !== "2.0 166bhp")` perhaps?

Comment: Which action you are performing? Can u include some more details and explain ?

Comment: I mean connecting. If the user selects the car model = "wk" and an engine other than "2.0 166bhp". An error in the form of console.log will be returned stating that this connection type cannot be selected or something like that. Possibly some css modification.

Comment: The idea is to block the possibility of selecting a different engine for the "wk" model

Comment: Instead, consider only showing engines which can be used with the chosen car model - imho that is a much better user experience. Clicking something to be told it's not valid is frustrating.

Comment: @StudioTime Yes, I know it would be an interesting solution, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Add valid engines to `ModelType`:

```
    {
        name: "wk",
        price: 5000,
        engines: ["2.0 166bhp"]
    },
```

and in your jsx add to the input `disabled={!carModel?.engines?.includes(engine.name)}`:

```
                        {EngineTypes.map(engine =>
                            <label className={styles.button}>
                                <input onClick={addCarEngine} type="radio" name="Engine" value={engine.name} disabled={!carModel?.engines?.includes(engine.name)}/>
                                <span>{engine.name}</span>
                            </label>
                        )}
```

Comment: Is there any alternative?
Because I want all engines and vehicle models to be listed in separate boards. It is possible that I will be adding more exceptions of this type in the future